# Show $\mathbb Q (i\sqrt3 , -i\sqrt3, \sqrt2, -\sqrt2 )= \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 )$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

$\mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 ) \subseteq \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3 , -i\sqrt3, \sqrt2, -\sqrt2 )$ is trivial.

$\mathbb Q (i\sqrt3 , -i\sqrt3, \sqrt2, -\sqrt2 ) \subseteq \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 )$:

Need to show: $i\sqrt3 , -i\sqrt3, \sqrt2, -\sqrt2 \in \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 )$

So $i\sqrt3 \in \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 )$ so by field operations, $-i\sqrt3 \in \mathbb Q (i\sqrt3, \sqrt2 )$.

Similar with $\sqrt2$.

I have a feeling that this is very wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct! Your arguments are correct!

Comment: woot woot!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments make sense but it need not look so complicated. Fields are closed under multiplication and $-1\in\mathbb{Q}$.